# Get array of int for array of strings using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Given an array of strings, I want to count the number of '1' character in each of the strings.

Example:

```
Input: ["00101010", "10010", "11111"]  
Output: [3, 2, 5]
```

```java
String []b = ["00101010", "10010", "11111"];
int [] c = Arrays.stream(b).mapToInt(r -> countChar(r, '1')).toArray();

int countChar(String string, char x) {
    return (int)string.chars().filter(ch -> ch == x).count();
}
```

How can I write this in a single statement?

I tried replacing `countChar(r, '1')` with `(int)string.chars().filter(ch -> ch == x).count()` and various combinations. The error log is too big for me to comprehend.

Comment: this seems more like a code review request

Comment: Even if the error log is too big for you to comprehend, you should post it so someone else can try to comprehend it.

Comment: Not a code review request as such.
I want to make use of Java parallel streams than writing complicated hand stitched parallel programming code.

Comment: If parallel code is your goal, you should have  mentioned that in your Question.

Comment: start correcting `String []b = ["00101010", "10010", "11111"];` which is not valid Java

Comment: Note that this example is unlikely to benefit from parallelization. The overhead of running it in parallel is probably higher than the cost of doing the actual work.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the `countChar(r, '1')` method call with the body of the method:

```
int[] c = Arrays.stream(b)
                .mapToInt(r -> (int) r.chars()
                                      .filter(ch -> ch == '1')
                                      .count())
                .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your characters are 0 and 1, then something like this should work. Remove all zeroes and the length of string is the number of ones. It's not the most efficient way as the replace method creates a throwaway string.

```
.stream()
.map(s -> s.replace("0", ""))
.mapToInt(String::length)
.toArray();
```

If you have other characters, you can create a regexp that replaces all characters except ones with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

### Code points, and parallel programming

Other Answers are good. But (a), I’d recommend making a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers when working with individual characters rather than using `char` type. And (b), you mentioned in a Comment that you want parallel programming.

The code point of the digit `1` is 49.

```
    int[] counts =
        Stream
        .of(  new String[] { "00101010", "10010", "11111" } )
        .parallel()
        .mapToLong( ( String s ) -> s.codePoints().filter( (int codePoint) -> codePoint == 49 ).count() )
        .mapToInt( Math :: toIntExact )
        .toArray() ;
```

Be aware that *parallel* does not necessarily mean *faster*.

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/34WwuE).